# string input, how to tell if it is int?

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I am writing a program that converts a parathensized expression into a mathematical one, and evaluates it. I've got the calculation bit written already.

I am using a stack for the operands, and a queue for the numbers. Adding operands to the stack isn't an issue, but I need to identify whether the input character is an integer, and if so, add it to the queue. Here's some code:

```
cout << "Enter the numbers and operands for the expression";
string aString;

do
{
   cin >> aString
   if (aString = int) // function to convert to read if int, convert to int
   {
    c_str(...);
    atoi(...);
    istack.push(int);
   }
 }
```

That's where I'm stuck now. I know I'm going to have to use c_str and atoi to convert it to an int. Am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: `atof` doesn't convert to an `int`...

Comment: meant to type atoi - thanks for the correction!

Comment: Be careful when using atoi. In the way you're using it here it'd be ok.  But it is broken IMHO. It'll return 0 for failed conversion, and 0 for "0". Better to use sscanf.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `.fail()` method of the stream.

If you need the string too, you can read to a string first, then attempt to convert the string to an integer using a `stringstream` object and check `.fail()` on the stringstream to see if the conversion could be done.

```
cin >> aString;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << aString;
int n;
ss >> n;

if (!ss.fail()) {
  // int;
} else {
  // not int;
}
```

Comment: Why would the cin fail if I entered a number into a string? Should work fine, so it won't throw...

Comment: It wouldn't, hence the need to introduce stringstream object for conversion. `boost::lexical_cast` also uses this method internally IIRC.

Comment: Additionally, you can check if the whole input was valid by checking if ss.eof() == true. Otherwise "1234 abc" counts as a valid int representation.

Comment: `if (!ss)` would be better, as it would verify that all input was consumed.  Your code accepts "123Fd" as a number.

Comment: @pezcode: There's very few situations where checking `.eof()` in a stream is the best way to go.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't understand. I didn't mean to imply that checking .eof() alone is the way to go. It's just an addition to what Kos suggested.

Comment: ah, great Kos - your code cleared that up for me - I was thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: @MooingDuck, isn't operator! equivalent to fail() on streams?

Answer (score 2):

If you *expect* an integer, I would use `boost::lexical_cast`.

```
std::string some_string = "345";
int val = boost::lexical_cast<int>(some_string);
```

If it fails to cast to an integer, it will throw.  The [performance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html) is pretty reasonable, and it keeps your code very clean.

I am unaware of any non-throwing version.  You could use something like this, though I usually try to avoid letting exceptions control program flow.

```
bool cast_nothrow(const std::string &str, int &val) {
  try {
    val = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
    return true;
  } catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast &) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Edit:

I would not recommend your integer validation checking for structure like you described.  Good functions do one thing and one thing well.

Usually you'd want a more formal grammar parser to handle such things.  My honest advice is to embed a scripting language or library in your project.  It is non-trivial, so let someone else do the hard work.

If I actually tried to implement what you propose, I would probably do a stack based solution keeping the parenthesis levels at their own stack frame.  The simplest thing would just be to hard code the simple operators (parenthesis, add, sub, etc) and assume that the rest of everything is a number.

Eventually you'd want everything broken down into some expression type.  It might look something like this:

```
struct Expression {
  virtual ~Expression() {}
  virtual float value() const = 0;
};

struct Number : public Expression {
  virtual float value() const {return val;}
  float val;
};

struct AdditionOper : public Expression {
  virtual float value() const {return lhs->value() + rhs->value();}
  boost::shared_ptr<Expression> lhs;
  boost::shared_ptr<Expression> rhs;
};
```

I'd start by parsing out the parenthesis, they will determine the order of your expressions.  Then I'd split everything based on the numerical operands and start putting them in expressions.  Then you're left with cases like `3 + 4 * 6` which would require some some care to get the order of operations right.

Good luck.

Comment: This is a clever little solution here, but I'm not only expecting somebody to input a number - it can be an operand or parenthesis at any time. I believe it's going to be tested in a number of ways.

Comment: @SoFLy I would definitely recommend parsing the encapsulation constructs of the grammar fully before checking for the validity of integers.

Comment: @SoFLy added some additional info about the grammar.

Comment: I agree, if the grammar gets big then rolling up a hand-written parser can be tedious and error-prone. Maybe you'd be better off with, for example, boost::spirit or an external parser generator. Depends on the size of your problem

Answer (score 2):

I'll probably get flamed for this by the C++ purists.

However, sometimes the C++ library is just more work than the C library.  I offer this
solution to C developers out there.  And C++ developers who don't mind using some of the
features of the C library.

The whole check and conversion can be done in 1 line of C using the sscanf function.

```
   int intval;
   cin >> aString

   if (sscanf(aString.c_str(), "%d", &intval)){
       istack.push(intval);
   }
```

sscanf returns the number of input arguments matched and assigned.  So in this case, it's looking for one standard signed int value.  If sscanf returns 1 then it succeeded in assigning the value.  If it returns 0 then we don't have an int.

Comment: this is actually a great piece of c code, clever - may fit this in there somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either run your function that converts a string representation of a number to a double and see if there's an error, or you can look at the contents of the string and see if it matches the pattern of a number and then do the conversion.

You might use `boost::lexical_cast<double>()` or `std::stod()` (C++11) where errors are reported with an exception, or istringstream extractors where the error is reported by setting the fail bit, or with C conversion functions that report errors by setting the global (thread local, rather) variable `errno`.

```
try {
    istack.push_back(std::stod(aString));
} catch(std::invalid_argument &e) {
    // aString is not a number
}
```

or

```
errno = 0;
char const *s = aString.c_str();
char *end;
double result = strtod(s,&end);
if(EINVAL==errno) {
    // the string is not a number
} else {
    istack.push_back(result);
}
```

An implementation of the second option might use a regex to see if the string matches the pattern you use for numbers, and if it does then running your conversion function. Here's an example of a pattern you might expect for floating point values:

```
std::regex pattern("[+-]?(\d*.\d+|\d+.?)([eE][+-]?\d+)?");
if(std::regex_match(aString,pattern)) {
    istack.push_back(std::stod(aString));
} else {
    // aString is not a number
}
```

Also, this probably doesn't matter to you, but most any built in method for converting a string to a number will be locale sensitive one way or another. One way to isolate yourself from this is to use a stringstream you create and imbue with the classic locale.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the C++ (no boost) way would be this :

```
do
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  std::string test;
  cin >> test;
  ss << test;
  int num;
  if (ss >> num) // function to convert to read if int, convert to int
  {
    std::cout << "Number : " << num << "\n";
  }
}while(true); // don't do this though..
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use `ctype.h`  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/. I have used this before and did not get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you're doing base-10 input, I find the most blatant thing to do is read the string, then check that it only contains valid characters:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
if(strrspn(s.c_str(), "0123456789")==s.length()){
    //int
} else{
    //not int
}
```